# @AspectJ pointcut for execute methods of a package

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I want to execute a execute method in a specific package.

What could be a possible pointcut for this?

Note: I am using @AspectJ style Spring AOP.

Comment: Please be more detailed. SO... you have a method you want to invoke called execute(), and where do you want to execute it from?

Comment: If i understand you correctly you need the following
execution(* com.company..*(..))
if we talk about execution pointcut

Comment: thanx  SirVaulterScoff this can be worked for every methods in a package but i want to execute a specific method named abc then where did i need to provide it ?

Comment: Considering spring-aop you should have something like this:
<aop:advisor advice-ref="myAdvice" pointcut="execution(* com.mycompany..*(..))" order="1"/>
Obviosly you should have spring bean called myAdvice which implements org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look here http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html

> `@(org.xyz..*)` Matches any annotated element which has either an
>   annotation of a type matching the type pattern `(org.xyz..*)`. In other
>   words, an annotated element with an annotation that is declared in the
>   org.xyz package or a sub-package. (The parenthesis are required in
>   this example).

So you should have the following aop config:

```
<aop:config>
 <aop:advisor advice-ref="myAdvice" pointcut="execution(* com.mycompany..*(..))" order="1"/> 
</aop:config>
```

and matching bean for this advice

```
<bean id="myadvice" class="com.mycompany.MyIntercetpor"/>
```

Interceptor should implement  org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor