# Pointcut matching all methods of all interfaces of a specific package

Tags: java, aspectj

Need to create an aspect that matches for all methods of all interfaces inside a package.

This method should be intercepted:

```
public interface IResource
{
void doSomething();
}
```

but this method not:

```
public class Resource
{
public void doSomethingElse()
{
...
}
}
```

I know there is a syntax with IResource+, but how can I use this for all interfaces? Is there another way?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802980/aspectj-pointcut-for-execute-methods-of-a-package